# What is the position of the United Methodist Church on creationism and evolution

Tags: creation, evolution, methodist

[Reverend Paul Kottke, of the United Methodist Church](http://www.umc.org/news-and-media/science-and-faith-9th-evolution-weekend-ahead), has preached that Christian faith and science, including Charles Darwin’s theory of evolution, are not incompatible. This seems to be in accord with the views of other denominations such as the Catholic Church and the Episcopal Church, but what is the official position of the United Methodist Church.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Methodist_Church) ranks the United Methodist Church as the third largest Christian denomination in the United States, and the largest denomination within the wider Methodist movement, worldwide.

Answer (score 9):

> The official statement on Science and Technology says in part, "We find that science’s descriptions of cosmological, geological, and biological evolution are not in conflict with theology.
>
> The Church also opposes introducing theories such as Creationism or Intelligent Design into public school curriculum.

http://www.umc.org/what-we-believe/what-is-the-united-methodist-churchs-position-on-evolution

http://www.umc.org/what-we-believe/the-natural-world#science-tech